# CSS Flexbox: How to set same Height to all <li> Items independent of different Font Sizes?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, flexbox, mobile-website

Assumed we have a **classic dropdown navigation** on a mobile website layout. All menue items are displayed below each other:

[image]

```css
ul.level_1,
ul.level_2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul.level_1 a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

ul.level_2 a {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.75em;
    padding-top: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
     <ul class="level_1">
         <li> bla </li>
         <li> bla </li>
         <li>
             <ul class="level_2">
                 <li> bla </li>
                 <li> bla </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

With same font sizes this is pretty easy, but:

**Challenges:**

- Menue items of main menue `ul.level_1` have `font-size 1.5rem`
- Menue items of sub menue `ul.level_2` have `font-size 1.2rem`

Therefore I want all `<li>` items to have the same height, so push buttons will have the same height later.

When I simply add a `padding` to the hyperlinks, the box heights will increase, **but** depending on the corresponding font size.

Is there an option available to specify the height of `<li>` items **independent** of the font size of its contained text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `em` unit is proportional to the font size. The simple answer is therefore to use an absolute unit like `px`.

Is there any reason that you cannot just set the height of the anchors in pixels like so?

```css
ul.level_1,
ul.level_2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul.level_1 a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    min-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.level_2 a {
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
     <ul class="level_1">
         <li> <a>bla</a> </li>
         <li> <a>bla</a> </li>
         <li>
             <ul class="level_2">
                 <li> <a>bla</a> </li>
                 <li> <a>bla</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```